# Can't record MusicLab Real Guitar from Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro

I open up a new Logic Pro X project and select the `External MIDI` interface.

I load the plugin to this track by going to `AU instruments` -> `MusicLab` -> `RealGuitar` -> `Stereo`

The interface opens up without any problem.

But when I try to record, this happens:

[image: logic]

As you can see, even though I am recording no track is showing up in Logic.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, if you go down to your AUs and open RealGuitar and the app works fine but won't record. What you have to do is either use an external keyboard, or if you want to do it in Logic, open the Logic on-screen keyboard, then it will record. For some reason the RealGuitar keyboard won't record. I hope this helps.